# How do I create a testRunner XML file using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3mZn.png)

Error Message Received During Runtime

How do I create a testRunner XML Regression Suite file for Selenium Webdriver? The following code does not link back to the tests specified. Not sure how to link the tests to the XML file.

I've attempted different XML runner files but none work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name = "Admin Users">
<test name = "Administrator Role Pages">
    <classes>
        <class name = 
"src/test/java/IRIS/test/IRIS_FMA/Surveys/SurveyPageChanges"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, you need to provide [fully qualified class name](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/get-the-fully-qualified-name-of-a-class-in-java), not the path to the file.

So it should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite">
    <test name="selenium-java">
        <classes>
            <class name="SurveyPageChanges"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

or if your class belongs to a [package](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_packages.asp) - you need to specify the package as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite">
    <test name="selenium-java">
        <classes>
            <class name="IRIS_FMA.Survey.SurveyPageChanges"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

More information:

- [testng.xml](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml)
- [How to set up and run Selenium tests, using various builders and Java test frameworks](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/selenium_builder_java/)